# How can I use the new reflection API to tell if the component type of an array conforms to a type parameter?

Tags: scala, reflection, manifest

If I have a method...

```
def arrayConformsTo[A](as: Array[_]) = ???
```

... where I can add *Context Bounds* to `A` as needed. I want this method to look at the component type of the `Array` and return true if this is a subtype of `A`. So, for example:

```
arrayConformsTo[Int](Array(1, 2, 3)) //returns true

arrayConformsTo[String](Array(1, 2, 3)) //returns false
```

Prior to 2.10, this would have been done as follows:

```
def arrayConformsTo[A: Manifest](as: Array[_]) = 
  ClassManifest.fromClass(as.getClass.getComponentType) <:< manifest[A]
```

However this now compiles with deprecation warnings

```
<console>:8: warning: method <:< in trait ClassManifestDeprecatedApis is deprecated: Use scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag for subtype checking instead
       ClassManifest.fromClass(as.getClass.getComponentType) <:< manifest[A]
                                                         ^
<console>:8: warning: value ClassManifest in object Predef is deprecated: Use scala.reflect.ClassTag instead
       ClassManifest.fromClass(as.getClass.getComponentType) <:< manifest[A]
```

My first guess at this is as follows:

```
scala> def arrayConformsTo[A: reflect.ClassTag](as: Array[_]) =
     | reflect.ClassTag(as.getClass.getComponentType) <:< implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[A]]
```

But this gives a deprecation warning as well

```
<console>:8: warning: method <:< in trait ClassManifestDeprecatedApis is deprecated: Use scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag for subtype checking instead
       reflect.ClassTag(as.getClass.getComponentType) <:< implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[A]]
                                                  ^
```

It tells me to use `TypeTag`. But how? Is this even a valid thing to ask of reflection?

---

Appendix: this seems to work reasonably well for what I need, although it does not work for `AnyVal`:

```
scala> def arrayConformsTo[A: reflect.ClassTag](as: Array[_]) =
     | implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass isAssignableFrom as.getClass.getComponentType
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scala reflection api sure is quite a labyrinth, but at least it is comprehensive:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
def arrayConformsTo[A: ru.TypeTag](as: Array[_]) = {
  val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror( getClass.getClassLoader )
  val classSym = mirror.classSymbol( as.getClass.getComponentType )
  classSym.toType <:< implicitly[ru.TypeTag[A]].tpe
}
```

REPL test:

```
scala> arrayConformsTo[Float]( Array[Float]() )
res9: Boolean = true

scala> arrayConformsTo[Int]( Array[Float]() )
res10: Boolean = false

scala> arrayConformsTo[AnyVal]( Array[Float]() )
res11: Boolean = true

scala> arrayConformsTo[AnyVal]( Array[Float]() )
res12: Boolean = true

scala> arrayConformsTo[Any]( Array[Float]() )
res13: Boolean = true

scala> arrayConformsTo[Any]( Array[Float]() )
res14: Boolean = true

scala> arrayConformsTo[AnyRef]( Array[Float]() )
res15: Boolean = false

scala> arrayConformsTo[AnyRef]( Array[Float]() )
res16: Boolean = false
```

---

*(This edit by the OP for reasons of completeness)*

Another solution (not requiring `scala-reflect.jar`), albeit one which does not preserve the `Float <:< AnyVal is true` property is to use a `ClassTag` as an extractor:

```
scala> def arrayConformsTo[A](as: Array[_])(implicit arrayOfA: ClassTag[Array[A]]) 
     | = as match {
     |     case arrayOfA(_) => true
     |     case _           => false
     |   }
```

Comment: That's great! If you don;t mind, I'm going to edit your answer to give another solution as well before accepting it

Answer (score 1):

This works for me w/o any compiler warnings:

```
def arrayConformsTo[A](as: Array[_])(implicit t:ClassTag[A]) = {
  ClassTag(as.getClass().getComponentType()) equals t
}
```

Then this prints `true` and then `false`

```
println(arrayConformsTo[Int](Array(1,2,3)))
println(arrayConformsTo[String](Array(1,2,3)))
```

Comment: But this does not work for `AnyVal` nor `Any`, just like the latest implementation from oxbow_lakes in his appendix.